# How do I get HTML elements with quotation marks into a Bootstrap popover?

Tags: javascript, html, quotation-marks

My Bootstrap Popover button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="CONTENT">
   Popover Text
</button>
```

I want to get this HTML into the data-content so it displays when the popover is clicked:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "RentalHistories", new { id = item.RentalHistoryId })">
   EDIT
</a>
```

Unfortunately the Quotes in the HTML seem to break it.
I have tried using single quotes, double quotes and the escape quote code &quot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what youre looking for:

```js
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-content='<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "RentalHistories", new { id = item.RentalHistoryId })">
   EDIT
</a>'>
   Popover Text
</button>

</body>
</html>
```

It seems its also important for which version of bootstrap you are using. From researching a bit, some of the older bootstrap versions did not require you to put something like 'data-bs-placement' but instead 'data-placement'. Here I am using Bootstrap version 5.0.

Bootstrap 5.0 DOCS also shows you can initialize a popover to appear visible by using (adding to your .js file or adding a  tag:

```
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
})
```

Another thing is that you were right to use single quotes to begin with because double quoting with nested double quotes can cause confusion when executed.

References:

[Bootstrap 5.0 Popovers DOCS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/popovers/)

[Reason for data-bs instead of data-attribute](https://www.sitepoint.com/bootstrap-5-new-features-examples/#changeindataattributes)